# selected value from dropdownlist doesnt select the value

Tags: angular, material-design, dropdown, observer-pattern, selectedvalue

I have a Angular 8 application and I have a dropdownlist. The content of the dropdownlist comes from the backend.

But if I select a value from the dropdownlist the value stays undefined or not selected.

But if I do a hardcoded value then it works.

This is the dropdownlist:

```
 filterByQrCodes() {
    this.participantService
      .filterParticipantsByQRCode(1, this.selectedValue as any, moment(this.startDate).format("YYYY MM D"), this
        .selectedValueOptie as any)
      .subscribe(filterByQrcode => {
        console.log(filterByQrcode);
        console.log("selectedValue", this.selectedValue as any);
        console.log("selectedValueOption", this.selectedValueOptie);
        this.filterParticipantByQrcode.emit(filterByQrcode);
      });

    this.showDropdownChallenge = true;
  }
```

and this is the template:

```
  <div  class="search-select searchoptions"  *ngIf="showDropdownVcheqCode && selectedSearch"   >
          <mat-select placeholder="Opties" name="option" [(ngModel)]="selectedValueOptie" (change)="getVcheqCodes()">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of (returnEcheqCodes$ | async)" value="option.value"> {{ option.title }} </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </div>
```

but if I select a value I get this error:

```
error:
EcheqFamilyId: ["The value 'option.value' is not valid for EcheqFamilyId."]
__proto__: Object
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure response for https://dev-engine.mijnhep.nl/api/medical/organisation/1/Participant/filter-by-echeq?Filter=New&Start=2019%2010%203&EcheqFamilyId=option.value: 400 Bad Request"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 400
statusText: "Bad Request"
```

But for example if I do this:

```
filterByVchecCode() {
    this.participantService
      .filterParticipantsByEcheq(1, this.selectedValue as any, moment(this.startDate).format("YYYY MM D"),
        "4597544a-f402-4bd0-870e-cc053ddf7cd0")
      .subscribe(filterByEcheqCode => {
        console.log(filterByEcheqCode);
        console.log("SelectedValueOption", this.selectedValueOptie as any);
        this.filterParticipatnByVcheqCode.emit(filterByEcheqCode);
      });
  }
```

Then I get the correct data back.

If I have to put some more information. You can say it

oke, if I do this:

```
      <div  class="search-select searchoptions"  *ngIf="showDropdownVcheqCode && selectedSearch"   >
          <mat-select placeholder="Opties" name="option" [(ngModel)]="selectedValueOptie" (change)="getVcheqCodes()">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of (returnEcheqCodes$ | async)" value="{{option.value}}"> {{ option.title | json }} </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </div>
```

Then I will get this error:

```
EcheqFamilyId: Array(1)
0: "The EcheqFamilyId field is required."
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

if I do this:

```
  console.log(this.selectedValueOptie);
```

it is also empty I mean blank

Comment: try to replace `value` with `[value]`. hope after this change it will work fine.

Comment: can you create an example with your current scenario in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) as it will be really helpful for the community for better understanding and for resolving your problem in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Your binding syntax seems to be wrong, use it like this -

```
[value]="option?.value"
```

or

```
value="{{option?.value}}"
```

First pattern for binding is always recommended while using angular for cleaner code style.

Also it would be better to use `?` elevis operator while dealing with async calls (data), it will avoid warning/errors produced by falsy value.

Comment: What do you mean?  kindly cross check?

Comment: your stackblitz demo is not in working state, check that.

Comment: But I created a new component. You see that?

Comment: I see this: Hello Angular!

Start editing to see some magic happen :)

Comment: @mightycodeNewton I would suggest you to try a little change and check if working as said in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simple interpolation mistake. Use `{{option.value}}` instead of  `option.value`

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let option of (returnEcheqCodes$ | async)" value="{{option.value}}"> {{ option.title }} </mat-option>
```

Comment: @mightycodeNewton That stackblitz is empty. Please provide a proper demo.

Comment: @mightycodeNewton save the files then click on the fork and then share the editor URL.

Comment: @mightycodeNewton You have to provide your full code there. Not just a sample project

Comment: That code is hard to understand without knowing the types of your properties.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the solution. But it works. I made a change like this:

```
 returnEcheqCodes$: EcheqFamilyInfo[];
```

and in the ngOniit:

```
this.echeqDefinitionService.listEcheqFamilies().subscribe(result => {
      this.returnEcheqCodes$ = result;

    });
```

and in the template without the async pipe:

```
 <div  class="search-select searchoptions"  *ngIf="showDropdownVcheqCode && selectedSearch">
          <mat-select placeholder="Opties" name="option" [(ngModel)]="selectedValueOptie" >
            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of returnEcheqCodes$ " value="{{option.family}}" > {{ option.title}} </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </div>
```

And this seems to work. But I don't understand this soluiton. Because I have a other dropdownlist with also is populated with data from the backend and I can use the async. But oke.